# Django: Queryset filter with multilevel nesting

Tags: python, django

The use case is the following: I'm trying to retrieve all Prospects that were generated under a Manager. The models are as follow: Prospect <---> Appointment <---> Staff <---> Manager. As you can see, there is no direct relationship between a prospect and a manager so I'm forced to do a nested, reverse lookup through the other models.

For example, I try to retrieve the prospects generated under Manager id=2 through the following query:

```
Prospect.objects.filter(appointment=Appointment.objects.filter(staff__manager=Manager.objects.get(user=2)))
```

But then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Any hint about what's wrong with my query?

Models.py

```
class Prospect(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_time = models.DateTimeField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    manager = models.ManyToManyField(Manager, through=Manager.staff.through, related_name='+', blank=True)
    unit = models.ManyToManyField(Unit, through=Unit.staff.through, related_name='+', blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic', blank=True)

class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField('Staff', related_name='+', blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo_image', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make it too complex, you can use double underscores (`__`) to follow a relation, Django also conceptually has bidirectional relations, so you also query `ForeignKey`s, etc. in "reverse":

```
Prospect.objects.filter(appointment__staff__manager_user_id=2)
```

You can use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve *unique* `Prospect`s:

```
Prospect.objects.filter(appointment__staff__manager_user_id=2).distinct()
```

The reason your query does not work is because your `Appointment.objects.filter(..)` query is a collection of `Appointment`s, you can query with:

```
Prospect.objects.filter(
    appointment__in=Appointment.objects.filter(
        staff__manager=Manager.objects.get(user=2)
    )
)
```

But regardless, this will increase the number of queries with one, and is thus less efficient.

Comment: Yes, I tried this earlier but my problem is that a Prospect may have one ore many Appointments. So this query set might show the same Prospect more than once. For example, say I have 4 appointments: 2 scheduled by Jonn, and 2 by Mary. The query looks like this: <QuerySet [<Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>, <Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>]>. I'm trying to output each Prospect ONLY once like so: <QuerySet [<Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>]>. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @MaximVallee: in that case you can use `.distinct()` to filter out the duplicates :)

Comment: Yes, exactly! I didn't know about this method, that's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `appointment=x`, x must be 1 appointment.  (if you want it to check against multiple, you can use `appointment__in=x`.

So you can change it to:

```
appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(staff__manager=Manager.objects.get(user=2))[0]  # see [0]
Prospect.objects.filter(appointment=appointment)
```

see this possible duplicate post: [The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing. Filter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994907/the-queryset-value-for-an-exact-lookup-must-be-limited-to-one-result-using-slici)

Comment: Yes, your __in solution works but not exactly as I intended. The query set is showing the same Prospect more than once. For example, say I have 4 appointments: 2 scheduled by Jonn, and 2 by Mary. The query looks like this: <QuerySet [<Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>, <Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>]>. I'm trying to output each Prospect ONLY once like so: <QuerySet [<Prospect: John>, <Prospect: Mary>]>. Is there something I'm missing?